Error while trying to run a launch file "Caught exception when trying to load file of format [yaml]: Expected only one root"
Error message:
Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [yaml]: Caught exception when trying to load file of format [yaml]: Expected only one root

I have however launched multiple other files in the same workspace, but for this particular one I am failing to do so. These are the steps:
shun@shun-vm:~/robot_ws$ source install/local_setup.bash
shun@shun-vm:~/robot_ws$ ros2 launch robot_bringup turtlebot3_tf.launch.yaml
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/shun/.ros/log/2024-05-05-18-28-28-000635-shun-vm-31565
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [yaml]: Caught exception when trying to load file of format [yaml]: Expected only one root

My turtlebot3_tf.launch.yaml file runs as:
launch:

- node:
    pkg: "tf2_ros"
    exec: "static_transform_publisher"
    name: "base_footprint_to_base_link"
    args: '0.0 0.0 0.01 0.0 0.0 0.0 my_base_footprint my_base_link'


- node:
    pkg: "tf2_ros"
    exec: "static_transform_publisher"
    name: "base_link_to_camera_link"
    args: '0.015 0.0913 0.0945 -1.571 0.0 -1.571 my_base_link my_camera_link'


- node:
    pkg: "tf2_ros"
    exec: "static_transform_publisher"
    name: "base_link_to_imu_link"
    args: '0.0 0.0 0.068 0.0 0.0 0.0 my_base_link my_imu_link'    


- node:
    pkg: "tf2_ros"
    exec: "static_transform_publisher"
    name: "base_link_to_laser_frame"
    args: '-0.09, 0.0 0.114 0.0 0.0 0.0 my_base_link my_laser_frame'  



I found the problem.
There was another launch file named "turtlebot3_tf.launch.yaml" in another package. Having deleted that and running "colcon build", closing the terminal and opening a new one to launch the file and voila! It worked!
Update: I had the same error again a month later now and the solution wasn't the same. This type the error was due to the .yaml launch file not being indented correctly. After having indented the lines correctly, the error was resolved.
